# Converting sql to Treeview JSON with C#

Tags: c#, sql, angularjs, json, treeview

I got a stored procedure fetching this table. I want to format it like this:

```
              data: [
                    { text: "Furniture", items: [
                        { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
                        { text: "Sofas" },
                        { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                    ] },
                    { text: "Decor", items: [
                        { text: "Bed Linen" },
                        { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                        { text: "Carpets" }
                    ]
```

Having trouble in converting it to JSON using my stored proc. Output is in kendo-tree-view using angularjs.

[image]

Comment: You need to get the record from the database using store procedure and write code in javascript to convert that record to tree-like structure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is more to do with more how to translate the database results into the structure for the treeview rather than binding the data this hopefully goes part of the way to answer the question. If not then I'll remove it or modify it. (I've had to make some assumptions based on the limited amount of info)

This all depends on how you are getting the data via the stored procedure. Are you using an ORM e.g. EF or Dapper or standard SqlClient connections/commands or a.n.other method of accessing this data.

So assuming you have a model similar to this:

```
public class treeviewItems
{
      public int id {get;set;}
      public int parentid {get;set;}
      public string text {get;set;}
      public List<treeviewItems> items {get;set;}
      public treeviewItems()
      {
        items = new List<treeviewItems>();
      }


}
```

Now that we have the model we need to transform the data into a way to get the data in this form. eg. Your `Json` example.

If we get the rows as flat lines we would need to iterate through the rows and populate the collection e.g. `IList<treeviewItems>`

if using Dapper you could always map the sub items like this:

```
var model = Context.Query<treeviewItems,treeviewItems,treeviewItems>(
`sql statement here`, 
(parent, child) => parent.items = child;return parent;},
new { `sql parameters if needed`}).ToList();
```

If using this method it is important that the column names match the property names and are in the correct order otherwise the mapping can go a bit wild.

so the column order would be the parent items first followed by the child items.

so for example:

```
id, parentid, text ==> From your top grouping table 
IDGROUP, 0, GROUP ==> based from your example table 

id, parentid, text ==> From you items table 
IDITEM, IDGROUP, ITEM ==> based from your example table
```

Obviously you can slice and dice the info how you want. 
This should then give you the data is the `right` structure to be able to present back to your treeview.

If you are using an ORM/SqlClient then you should be able to achieve the same results using LINQ to manipulate the data into this structure

Comment: Hi @David, Thanks for this, it gives me idea to the flow. I found the simplest answer in youtube that applies to my situation. I reformatted my query so I can use the parent as NULL. Ill post the answer. Cheers!